# ios - UICollectionView layout last row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am currently working on a **UICollectionView**. I have been looking all over SO and found several issues to this problem, but none of those had an answer to the problem. Maybe if i collect all the facts in one question here, one can provide a solution to this issue:

If I have a collectionView with a simple UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass, all works fine but the last row. I do **everything with autoLayout**. The cells align just fine, they fill out the row as soon as a new row starts. The only problem there is that **the last row's layout** is still as it would wait for another item to be added.

Now, some code, here's my UICollectionViewFlow subclass:

```
@implementation SubCollectionViewFlowLayout
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0f;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0f;
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the whole subclassing. So it really is just basic.

So when looking for another issue with this problem, i found the following SO Questions. The first one is exactly my probelm, the others seem to be similar.

- [UICollectionView layout of last cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860754/uicollectionview-layout-of-last-cell)
- [UICollectionView estimatedItemSize - last cell is not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566911/uicollectionview-estimateditemsize-last-cell-is-not-aligned)
- [UICollectionView last cell not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146480/uicollectionview-last-cell-not-aligned)
- [Last item in UICollectionView not alligned - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080257/last-item-in-uicollectionview-not-alligned-swift)

I hope this is enough description for the problem, help is as always much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I guess it is not possible to solve this smoothly.

However there is a possibility to solve it, described [in this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186435/1105464).

One just adds an additional cell with height=0 and width=collectionViewWidth. Tested this and works perfectly fine.

Comment: How did you set the width to the collection view? Where do you get the collection view width?